# Prove that $0<11 - 6 \sqrt{3} <1$

Tags: inequality

This point was used as part of a solution I was seeing. A way to do it with approximation is using taylor's theorem:

$$ \sqrt{3} \approx \sqrt{4} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4} } = 1.75$$ and hence we find that $$ 11-6 \sqrt{3}\approx.5$$

But, are there ways to prove the above without appealing to taylor's theorem?

P.s: I would prefer a proof which is not based on contradiction methods.

Comment: Proving this inequality gives you $\frac{10}{6} < \sqrt3 < \frac{11}{6}$ after some rearrangement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Originally a comment and similar to Gae. S.:*

You could say $$\begin{matrix} & 121 &>& 108 &>& 100 \\ \implies& \sqrt{121} &>& \sqrt{108} &>& \sqrt{100}\\ \implies& 11 &>& 6 \sqrt{3} &>& 10\\ \implies& -11 &<& - 6 \sqrt{3} &<& -10\\ \implies &0 &<& 11- 6 \sqrt{3} &<& 1\end{matrix}$$

Answer (score 5):

Let the roots of a quadratic be $11 - 6\sqrt3$ and $11 + 6\sqrt3$. Then their sum is $22$ and their product is $(11 - 6 \sqrt3)(11 + 6 \sqrt3) = 11^2 - 6^2 \cdot 3 = 13$, leading to the quadratic $f(x) = x^2-22x+13$.

Then $f(0) = 13$ but $f(1) = -8$, and since $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are of opposite signs,  there must be a root in between $0$ and $1$ (IVT in disguise), and it cannot be $11 + 6 \sqrt3$. Thus $0 < 11 - 6 \sqrt3 < 1$.

Comment: Good answer! I would never have thought of bringing in a polynomial to it

Comment: Once you have $11 - 6 \sqrt3$, you think of $11 + 6 \sqrt3$, and that leads on very nicely to this approach.

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt3\ge0$, therefore \begin{align}&11-6\sqrt3>0\Leftrightarrow 11>6\sqrt3\Leftrightarrow 121>36\times 3=108\\ &11-6\sqrt3<1\Leftrightarrow 10<6\sqrt3\Leftrightarrow 100<108\end{align}

Comment: +1: You could say $121 > 108 > 100$ $\implies \sqrt{121} > \sqrt{108} > \sqrt{100}$ $\implies 11 > 6 \sqrt{3} > 10$ $\implies -11 < - 6 \sqrt{3} < -10$  $\implies 0 < 11- 6 \sqrt{3} < 1$ which is much the same

Comment: @Henry Your comment deserves its own answer. Go for it!

Comment: @Henry Well, I guess. It isn't like I'm hanging this in my living room.

Answer (score 1):

Using the difference of two squares identity:

$$0<11 - 6 \sqrt{3} < 1 \Longleftrightarrow 0 < 11^2-6^2\cdot3<11+6 \sqrt3 \Longleftrightarrow 0 < 13 < 11 + 6 \sqrt3$$

and this is true since $0<13 < 11 + 6 \cdot 1 < 11 + 6 \sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

@Henry's comment should be the answer!  {I wrote this answer before seeing Henry's comment}

For $x>0$ we have
$$
x-6\sqrt3 > 0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad x>6\sqrt{3}
 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad x^2 > 108
$$
Investigate when $x$ is a perfect square, $10^2 = 100 < 108 < 121 = 11^2$.  Therefore
$$
10-6\sqrt3 < 0,\quad 11-6\sqrt3 > 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem by using a suitable rational approximation to $\sqrt 3$, which can be derived from its [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expansion and [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

The primitive solution to the Pell's equation for $\sqrt3$ is
$$2^2 - 3\cdot 1^2 = 1$$
Thus
$$(2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)=1$$
and for any $n$,
$$(2+\sqrt3)^n(2-\sqrt3)^n=1$$
This gives us all of the best rational approximations for $\sqrt3$. If
$$p^2 -3q^2 = 1$$
then
$$\left(\frac pq\right)^2 = 3 + \frac 1{q^2}$$
Let
$$p_n + \sqrt3 q_n = (2+\sqrt3)^n$$
Then
$$p_{n+1}=2p_n + 3q_n$$
$$q_{n+1}=p_n + 2q_n$$
Let $p, q$ be any such solution pair. Then
$$\sqrt3<\frac pq$$
and
$$3<\sqrt3\frac pq$$
so
$$\frac{3q}p<\sqrt3<\frac pq$$

---

We can solve the OP's problem by looking for a sufficiently large $p,q$ pair.

$$\frac{-6p}q<-6\sqrt3<\frac{-18q}p$$
$$\frac{11q-6p}q<11-6\sqrt3<\frac{11p-18q}p$$

Let $a=11q-p$ and $b=11p-18q$.
We need to find $p,q$ such that $0<a/q$ and $b/p<1$. The first such pair occurs at $n=2$, with $p=7, q=4$.
$$p^2-3q^2=49-3\cdot16=1$$
$$\frac{44-42}4<11-6\sqrt3<\frac{77-72}7$$
$$0<\frac 12<11-6\sqrt3<\frac 57<1$$

---

We can get tighter bounds on $11-6\sqrt3\approx 0.6076951546$ by using larger $p, q$ pairs. Here's a table of the first eight results:

| $p$ | $q$ | $a/q$ | $b/p$ | $a/q$ | $b/p$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | -1 | 2 | -1.00000000000000 | 2.00000000000000 |
| 7 | 4 | 1/2 | 5/7 | 0.500000000000000 | 0.714285714285714 |
| 26 | 15 | 3/5 | 8/13 | 0.600000000000000 | 0.615384615384615 |
| 97 | 56 | 17/28 | 59/97 | 0.607142857142857 | 0.608247422680412 |
| 362 | 209 | 127/209 | 110/181 | 0.607655502392344 | 0.607734806629834 |
| 1351 | 780 | 79/130 | 821/1351 | 0.607692307692308 | 0.607698001480385 |
| 5042 | 2911 | 1769/2911 | 1532/2521 | 0.607694950188938 | 0.607695358984530 |
| 18817 | 10864 | 3301/5432 | 11435/18817 | 0.607695139911635 | 0.607695169261838 |